# actionscript 3 remove or stop for loop

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, for-loop

this is a part of my code:

```
private var sun:Sun;
private var aantalSun:int = 5;
private var counter:int;

for (counter = 0; counter < aantalSun; counter++)
{
    sun = new Sun();
    addChild(sun);
}
```

when the whole code is running, there is a button called 'menu' on the stage.
when i click that button, i want to go back to my main menu, but there are still 5 sun on my stage.
how can i remove the 5 sun (like, stop the loop?) when i click the menu button?
i already tried removeChild(sun);, but then only one sun goes away.

Answer (score 3):

Actually looping of 5 iterations will done so fast that you cant exit from the loop when a button is pressed.

What I understood is you want to remove the added 5 suns when the button is pressed.

What I would suggest is create parent of your 5 suns and add it to that and remove your parent so that all 5 childs will be removed. No need to maintain 5 childs references and you have to maintain only one parent reference.

Comment: You could also choose to store the children in an array as you add them, and remove them pretty much the same way.

Comment: Yes @AmyBlankenship but it takes bit code and time to maintain array. If we use the parent, then we can always access its elements and we can remove when not needed.

Comment: You still need extra code to add and refer to the parent. I think it's about the same, though I find that many people don't "think in collections."

Answer (score 0):

Stop the loop and exit it with the break command;
So if you have a condition that you can check like the var menuClicked you can make liek this:

```
for (counter = 0; counter < aantalSun; counter++)
{
 if(menuClicked) break;
 sun = new Sun();
 addChild(sun);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the "suns" in an array and loop trough this to remove all suns:

```
private var sun:Sun;   
private var aantalSun:int = 5;   
private var counter:int;
private var sunArray:Array = new Array();

for (counter = 0; counter < aantalSun; counter++) { 
    sun = new Sun();
    sunArray.push(sun);
    addChild(sun); 
} 

function RemoveSuns() {
    for (var i:int = 0; i < sunArray.length; i++) { 
        removeChild(sunArray[i]);
    } 
}
```

**OR** you remove ALL:

```
function RemoveAll() {
    for(var i:int = 0; i < this.numChildren; i++) {
        this.removeChildAt(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you need (rhe function at the bottom) as well as the small changes to your original posted code.

```
private var sun:Sun;
private var aantalSun:int = 5;
private var counter:int;

private var sunContainer:Sprite = new Sprite();
addChild(sunContainer);

for (counter = 0; counter < aantalSun; counter++)
{
    sun = new Sun();
    sunContainer.addChild(sun);
}




//function for clearing all suns
function clearSuns(e:Event = null):void {
    var i:int = sunContainer.numChildren;
    while(i--){
        sunContainer.removeChildAt(i);
    }
}
```